# Loop not returning

Tags: java, android

Using this code to check through the String "name" and see if the letters match, with any of the letters of the list uNamesList. Once a match is found I want it to return the match number in the array. Although, the result that gets returned is always the same being 5. 5 is the default result if no match is found, although I made sure that the EditText "name" always had similar characters to the strings in uNamesList.

```
uNamesList.add("bob");
uNamesList.add("mike");
uNamesList.add("sike");
uNamesList.add("othername");
uNamesList.add("name");



public int getName(EditText name) {
    int match = 1;
    String text = name.getText().toString();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { //i = current letter in text
        char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
            String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
            char uLetter = uName.charAt(i);
            if (cLetter == uLetter) {
                return o;
                //match = o;
                //found = true;
                //break;

            }
        }
        //if(found) break;
    }
   return match;
}
```

Commented code is just me trying to fix this since I assumed it was a looping issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name.toString()` is not the String you wish to match, since `name` is a `EditText` instance.

change

```
char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
```

to

```
char cLetter = text.charAt(i);
```

Even with this fix your code seems strange, since it would return a match even if just one character of the input text matches a respective character of a `uName` String.

You should probably use String::equals :

```
public int getName(EditText name) {
    int match = 1;
    String text = name.getText().toString();
    for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
        String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
        if (text.equals(uName)) {
            return o;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, holy crap this stuff is picky.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to see if a String from EditText 'name' is in the List and return it's position, maybe all you need is:

```
uNamesList.indexOf(name.getText().toString());
```